# How to make picturebox in C# clickable in visual Studio for maze design project?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was following this tutorial to make a Maze in Visual Studio using the Form template and C#, but I don't understand exactly how he makes the picture boxes into buttons and is able to make a form that allows users to manipulate the picture boxes to make the maze. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4a950c/solving-mazes-using-recursion/

```
private void createNewMaze()
{
mazeTiles = new PictureBox[XTILES, YTILES];
//Loop for getting all tiles
for (int i = 0; i < XTILES; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < YTILES; j++)
    {
        //initialize a new PictureBox array at cordinate XTILES, YTILES
        mazeTiles[i, j] = new PictureBox();
        //calculate size and location
        int xPosition = (i * TILESIZE) + 13; //13 is padding from left
        int yPosition = (j * TILESIZE) + 45; //45 is padding from top
        mazeTiles[i, j].SetBounds(xPosition, yPosition, TILESIZE, TILESIZE);
        //make top left and right bottom corner light blue. Used for start and finish
                if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == XTILES - 1 && j == YTILES - 1))
                    mazeTiles[i, j].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                else
                {
                    //make all other tiles white
                    mazeTiles[i, j].BackColor = Color.White;
                    //make it clickable
                    EventHandler clickEvent = new EventHandler(PictureBox_Click);
                    mazeTiles[i, j].Click += clickEvent; // += used in case other events are used
                }
                //Add to controls to form (display picture box)
                this.Controls.Add(mazeTiles[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I created the method too, but all i have is the regular picture box and and 2 buttons.

```
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        ((PictureBox)sender).BackColor = currentColor;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is ok, but if you chang ethe color to current color, it wont show any change.

Try this,

```
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Brown;
 }
```